# Driver Doesnt Work In Function / Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

i writing the an example test automation on python with page object model.

i make a base class and some functions to call others moduls.

when i make the func, driver doesnt open.But there is no any error message.
and when delete the func, driver works.

What is the main problem?

```
class Base():

  baseUrl = "https://www.example.com/"
  exec_path = "C:/Users/bzkles/PycharmProjects/example/driver/chromedriver.exe"

  def setUp(self):
     self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path= self.exec_path)
     self.driver.get(self.baseUrl)
     self.driver.maximize_window()

  def tearDown(self):
      self.driver.quit()
```

Comment: Where are you calling `setUp`? Please add that line. Something like `Base.setUp()`

Comment: class Base: is that a typo or error?